# How to fill a datagridView with my stored procedure on load

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that selects the top 10 results from its inner join

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS
    @JobID INT,
    @BatchID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT top(10) i.*
    FROM jobtable AS j
    INNER JOIN batchtable AS b ON j.JobID = b.JobID
    INNER JOIN imgtable AS i ON i.BatchID = b.BatchID
END
```

What I don´t know why it's not working is when I run the app the datagrid is just empty.

This next code is on my dataAccess class

```
public DataTable SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS_IBML1(int JobID, int BatchID)
{
        try
        {
            ManageConnectionStateIbml1();
            SqlCommand command = new 
            SqlCommand("SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS", connectionIBML1);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobId", JobID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchId", BatchID);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ManageConnectionStateIbml1();
            connectionIBML1.Close();
        }
}
```

And finally there is my Form file that I am trying to fill the dgv

```
private void FillDGVDocs(int JobID, int BatchID)
{
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Refresh();

        DataTable dt = da.SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS_IBML1 (JobID, BatchID);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Caixa";
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[2].HeaderText = "DOC";
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[3].HeaderText = "ID";
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[4].HeaderText = "PROC";
}
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It seems odd that the stored procedure doesn't actually use the parameters...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That stored procedure code is product specific.)

Comment: Also, those parameters aren't optional - yet you don't supply any parameters; are you sure you're not getting an exception about missing parameters? Side note: DataTable is almost always the wrong tool for any data related task. It was arguably more useful back in .NET 1.1 days, as a transition from recordsets

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server, based on the SqlCommand/etc

Comment: ah so i need to get the parameters into where ? @MarcGravell

Comment: @jarlh sql my friend

Comment: @Tiago `command.Parameters.Add(...)` would do that; note, I have no clue why you're using a data-adapter here, note (or DataTable, but that's a separate topic)

Comment: @Tiago re "sql my friend", the term "sql" is ambiguous; most rdbms talk some flavor of SQL. You might mean "SQL Server", which talks the TSQL variant of SQL

Comment: @MarcGravell i will put the two variables then but then  what do i need to put them somewhere else?

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear about what you mean there; I have no clue what you're asking

Comment: @MarcGravell im using msqlsms and the language is sql

Comment: @MarcGravell i want to display the information from the sp into the dgv

Comment: ill edit the code with what i updated

Comment: "im using msqlsms and the language is sql" - if by that you mean that you are using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, then: you're using SQL Server and the language is Transact-SQL, aka TSQL (waits for edit to show up)

Comment: @MarcGravell i edited with what i know i hope the picture on this problem is getting clearer

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the adapter is helping you here. You should just be able to use `DataTable.Load(IDataReader)`, using `command.ExecuteDataReader()` as the source; but frankly, and I can't stress this enough: DataTable is usually the wrong approach to any data problem

Comment: DataTable dt = da.SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS_IBML1(); I don' t see any input parameters. How are you getting them?

Comment: @Sergey my bad, forgot to edit that

Comment: @MarcGravell im trying to do the datatable. Load and the command.ExecuteDataReader is underlined from .ExecuteDataReader

Comment: Sorry, ExecuteReader()

Comment: @TiagoSilva You still haven't shown the real FillDGVDocs(). I see lots of errors there.

Comment: Edited with the filldgv @Sergey

Comment: @MarcGravell oh i see Marc well now the error is on the (IDataReader)

Comment: Anywhere i try to use the fillDGVDocs doensen´t work since i dont have the two variables

Comment: SQL is a _language_ specified by ISO/ANSI. The stored procedure part is named PSM (Persistent Stored Modules.) Most products, incl. MS SQL Server instead have their own versions of stored procedures.

Comment: 1. You are not opening the connection. Are you caching an open connection, that is not the correct way, you should create and open a new connection every time 2. Dispose your connection, command and adapter with `using` don't try writing your own cleanup 3. Does your DGV have `AutoGenerateColumns == true`?

Comment: @Charlieface i do have a conn string and its working so i do call the connection.And no my dgv does not have autoGenerateColumns i make them manually

Comment: You have shown no code for that, so yeah it will be blank as you've cleared the columns on every load.

Comment: @Charlieface ah ok then should i stop clearing them?

Comment: @Charlieface when i try to run the app it says that both my variables dont exist

Comment: Which variables, what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Charlieface Error goes as follows. The name 'JobID' does not exist in the current context and the same for BatchID

Comment: Your **original** [version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66314486/revisions) of your post said `public DataTable SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS_IBML1()` and did not declare the parameters, did you not actually change that in your code as others mentioned??

Comment: I did its changed ye @Charlieface

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!